# Angular : How to intercept Server-Sent Event request?

Tags: angular, server-sent-events, angular-http-interceptors

I've written an angular interceptor to add some headers to my requests. Everything's fine till the SSE request, it is not intercepted !

```js
@Injectable()
export class SessionUserDataInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(@Inject(SESSION_USER_DATA) private userData: SessionUserData) {}


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const setHeaders = {};

    if (this.userData.line) {
      setHeaders['Line'] = this.userData.line;
    }

    if (this.userData.profil) {
      setHeaders['Profil'] = this.userData.profil.id;
    }

    return next.handle(request.clone({setHeaders}));
  }
}
```

`SessionUserData` is just a wrapper for the `SessionStorage`.

I've tried to add the headers to my SSE connection but it's not working neither.

```
const es = new EventSource(url, {headers: {Line: 'XXX', Profil: 'YYY'}} as any);
```

Any help's appreciated.

Comment: Cory indicates that it's for known  Angular client requests.  SSE wouldn't be known to Angular.  https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/intro-to-angular-http-interceptors#:~:text=Interceptors%20are%20a%20unique%20type,the%20value%20of%20the%20request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpInterceptor` pattern only works for request sent by the `HttpClient`. Which means that `EventSource` is not captured, neither is an ordinary `XMLHttpRequest`. Best thing you could do is to move the actual transformation of your request in your interceptor to a utility function, which you can call inside your interceptor and perhaps a custom service which wraps the `EventSource` functionality

Comment: Just curious how would a utility gain access to an server side request, doesn't the browser prevent that?

Comment: @JohnPeters `EventSource` doesn't have header support indeed. This could be overcome by using the query string, a polyfill which does support it, or by using the `fetch` stream functionality

Comment: @JohnPeters also, it's a Server-Sent event, not a server side rendering request :) I guess the naming threw you off a bit

Comment: Sorry I misspoke I meant SSE

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'l not sure to understand what you mean from *Best thing you ...* Do you have exemples ?

Comment: @bubbles well, if it's headers you want to add to a `EventSource`, you won't be able to. Unless you somehow use the query params on the url, and handle it on the backend.

Comment: is there a way to decorate `EventSource` in a way it uses `HttpInterceptor` ?

Comment: @PoulKruijt do you know if the polyfill allows you to overwrite http headers? I'm trying to remove the Accept-Encoding header.